# Mongoose how filtered db after populate in object

Tags: mongoose, search, filter, find, populate

I need help. I'm having the trouble, I need to filter my DB after populate(). But it works incorrect(

Example:

Item model:

```
const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Translations'
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    currency: {
        type: String,
        default: '₴'
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Translations model:

```
const translationsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ru: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    en: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
});
```

Filtration:

```
const items = await Item.find()
            .populate({
                path: 'description',
                select: 'en'
            })
            .find({$or: [
                    {'description.en': 'search text'},
                    {'price': 100}
                ]})
            .exec();
```

Return empty array: `[]`

But expected behaviour should return an array with items which contain 'search text' in 'en' field or items which price = 100

Comment: I found the solution myself) It's aggregate()

Comment: Hi. are you can insert your solution, please? @AlexSerga